# How to keep style rules separate for different pages in Ionic2 apps?

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic2

I have three different files `app.scss`, `movie-info.scss`, `movie-list.scss`. The `app.scss` file has the following comment in it:

> Put style rules here that you want to apply globally. These styles are for the entire app and not just one component. Additionally, this file can be also used as an entry point to import other Sass files to be included in the output CSS.

This means the styles here will be applied to the whole app. For this reason, I put the styles for `movie-info` page inside `movie-info.scss`. However, the styles placed there still affect the `movie-list` page. Why is that? What is the purpose of using different `scss` files if the styles are being applied to the whole app?

Comment: can you put the movie-info.scss in the question?

Comment: @suraj Please wait. :)

Comment: 'For this reason, I put the styles for movie-info page inside movie-info.scss .' How did you add it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your movie-info.scss file, there should be a namespace set.
For example:

```
movie-info-page{
//css style here
}
```

This namespace is set in your component as *selector*.

```
@Component({
    selector: ' movie-info-page',
    templateUrl: 'movie-info.html',
})
```

Any style placed *within* the namespace is applied to the particular page.
All styles outside is set as global and will be set from the page to all subsequent pages.
If you want a global style for entire app, set in app.scss
Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks suraj. I understand the concept of style rules now. :)